# Error vue/typescript Cannot find module and it's path error can't find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, path, src

**Hi, I'm having this erreor while doing the Router view:
Cannot find module '@/src/views/HomeView.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
I had tried different paths and had changed the tsconfig.vue file, but still get the error.**

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    }
  ]
}


// router/index.ts

import HomeView from '@/src/views/HomeView.vue'
import HomeView from '@/views/HomeView.vue'

const routes = {
  '/': HomeView,
}
```

Comment: Is your file `index.js` or `index.ts`? Try to add `allowJS: true` in your tsconfig so typescript also consider the `.js` files. Also the `tsconfig` must be a json file, not js: `tsconfig.json`

Comment: my tsconfig ffile is .json, and my  router index file is .js, so I added the line allowJs: true to tsconfig.json root Object, but the error didn't disappear.